# setNeedsDisplay doesn't change UITableView's center

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, interface-builder, setneedsdisplay

Added a `UITableView` through **IB**. I'm trying to change the center of the `UITableView` programmatically:

```
- (IBAction)OnClickPrescribingDoctorButton:(id)sender
{
    [_prescribingDoctorTableView setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"check before %f",_prescribingDoctorTableView.center.y);

    _prescribingDoctorTableView.center = CGPointMake(50,200);

    NSLog(@"check after %f",_prescribingDoctorTableView.center.y);
}
```

**LOG:**

```
2014-04-21 13:40:18.898 SmartWatch[1833:70b] check before 788.000000
2014-04-21 13:40:18.898 SmartWatch[1833:70b] check after 200.000000

2014-04-21 13:40:20.075 SmartWatch[1833:70b] check before 788.000000
2014-04-21 13:40:20.075 SmartWatch[1833:70b] check after 200.000000
```

As you can see in the log, the **Y-axis value** of the `UITableView` changes but i don't see any effect visually or the `UITableView` being redrawn as i call **setNeedsDisplay** and i also don't understand why does **Y-axis value** value reverts back to 788 every time i call this code by clicking on a `UIButton`.

Comment: Just set frame your tableView and check whether it can change position?

Comment: @nmh I tried to change TableView's frame in `viewDidAppear`.Doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think you UITableView is hardcode somewhere (maybe always at this position), it is the reason you can not set frame. I test by my app, it works when I change the frame. Double check setFrame of this tableView in our application

Answer (score 0):

Try using [[_prescribingDoctorTableView superview] setNeedsLayout] instead of [_prescribingDoctorTableView setNeedsDisplay] to layout the subviews.

if this doesn't work, subclass your view and override the methods,

```
- (void)layoutSubviews (or) - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

And debug by placing the break point in these methods so that you can come to know from where your frame being updated.